# Is Zend OPCache the same thing as Zend Optimizer+

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

I'm in a process of upgrading the PHP across all of our servers to 5.5.x

I read that the PHP team will be integrating Zend Optimizer+ within the PHP core for the 5.5 release. So I installed that but in phpinfo() there's nothing about zend optimizer+, there are only few Zend OPCache directives. So my question is, am I looking at the same thing, or should 
I compile/install another extension and if so where can I find the latest version.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Here is repo for a proof: https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus
Zend have some troubles with naming: Zend Optmizer != Zend Optmizer+
Now, they've opensourced it, and it is called OPCache and bundles with 5.5.